# Will jboss seam 1.1 work with JSF 1.2?

Tags: jsf-1.2, jboss-seam

We have a legacy app which uses seam 1.1. Its deployed on websphere 7 which has JSF 1.2. So will it cause any problems? Are seam 1.1 and JSF 1.2 compatible?

Or do i need to upgrade the version of jboss seam which is compatible with jsf 1.2?

**EDIT 1:-**

The reason I am asking this question is that suddenly we are getting following erros

```
 application   E   JSF1007: Duplicate component ID listForm:j_id_jsp_768167483_47:templateItems:j_id_jsp_768167483_77 found in view.
```

Another team has said that its because of the version mismatch of JSF being used in app and the JSf version supported by websphere 7 which is 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, They both are compatible and will cause no problems.

Comment: Please see I have updated my question to add the errors I am getting.